# App Not Downloading Newest Version Of File [Java]

Tags: java, caching, download

Okay, I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours and it's starting to kill me.

I wrote a primitive version checker for an app I work on every once and awhile. It's just a simple for fun project.

The version checker has been a pain though. It was working the first few times I tested it, but since then it was been returning the same value over and over, despite the file it was reading from having been deleted. I can only assume this means it was cached somewhere, and caching a version file kind of ruins the point of having it.

Here's the code I use for checking the version number from my website:

```
    public int VersionNumber = 2005001; //to be updated to 2999999 when building to distribute
    public static boolean CheckUpdate() throws Exception {
        int ver = Integer.parseInt(getText("http://www.fragbashers.net/smite/version.txt"));
        System.out.println(ver);

    if (ver > VersionNumber) {
        System.out.println("Current version lower than newest!");
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

public static String getText(String url) throws Exception {
    URL website = new URL(url);
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream()));
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    String inputLine;

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
        response.append(inputLine);

    in.close();

    return response.toString();
}
```

I use

```
int ver = Integer.parseInt(getText("http://www.fragbashers.net/smite/version.txt"));
    URL newClient = new URL("http://www.fragbashers.net/smite/RGP_" + ver + ".jar");
```

and some JFileChooser code to download the new version. That causes no issues.

The file on my website has a 7 digit long int on it (2999999) that is the newest version file. Eclipse is printing out the old version (2005001).

Basically I need help figuring out why the file is being cached and how I can stop it from being cached so it always has the most up to date version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `URLConnection.setUseCaches(boolean);`.

In your case, it would be `connection.setUseCaches(false);`